# Package tikz error

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, packages, circuitikz

I have done a circuit with circuitikz, it was working just fine. But since I have installed beamer on my laptop (on linux), there are like a million mistakes on each line...

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}

% Package langue
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

%Packages mathématiques
\usepackage{amsmath} %Equations
\usepackage{hyperref}


%Packages Figures et graphiques
\usepackage{graphics} %inclusion de figures
\usepackage{graphicx} %inclusion de figures
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
%circuit node[label={$V_{in}$}]
\draw (0, 0) to[short,o-]  (10, 0)
(7,-4) -- (10,-4)
(0,-7) to[short,o-o]  (10,-7);
%composants
\draw (3,-4) to [Schottky diode] (3,0)
(7,0) to [ecapacitor] (7,-4)
(10,-4) to [R] (10,0)
(3,-4) to [inductor,l_=\SI{2}{\henry}] (7,-4);
%mosfet
\draw (3,-5.5) node[njfet] (fet) {} 
(fet.G) node[anchor=south]  {G}
(fet.D) node[anchor=north east] {D}
(fet.S) node[anchor=south east] {S};
\draw (9.5,-2.6) node[rotate=90,right]{10 $k \Omega$};
% circuit & labels
\draw (7.7,-2.4) node [rotate=90,right]{\SI{1}{\micro\farad}};
\draw (fet.D) -- (3,-4);
\draw (3,-7) -- (fet.S)
(5,-7) node[ground] {};
\draw [->,>=latex] (0,-6.8) -- (0,-0.2) node[below=0.7cm,right=0.1cm] {$V_{in}$};
\draw [->,>=latex] (10.5,-3.6) -- (10.5,-0.4) node[below=0.7cm,right=0.1cm] {$V_{out}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea or a clue to solve this mess ? It would be great ! Thanks a lot guys !!

S.C.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I compile with TeX Live 2012, I only get an error at `ecapacitor`; with TL 2013 or later, I get loads of error.

Comment: You solve the issue by adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`

Comment: @egreg it works fine now ! Thanks a lot for your answers, you save the day !! But what does your codeline do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you were using TeX Live 2012 and the new installation has a more recent TeX distribution.

You solve the issue by adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Also move `hyperref` last in the loaded packages. Loading `graphics` is not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Package langue
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

%Packages mathématiques
\usepackage{amsmath} %Equations


%Packages Figures et graphiques
\usepackage{graphicx} %inclusion de figures
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} %%% <--- Don't forget
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref} %%% <--- This should be last

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
%circuit node[label={$V_{in}$}]
\draw (0, 0) to[short,o-]  (10, 0)
(7,-4) -- (10,-4)
(0,-7) to[short,o-o]  (10,-7);
%composants
\draw (3,-4) to [Schottky diode] (3,0)
(7,0) to [ecapacitor] (7,-4)
(10,-4) to [R] (10,0)
(3,-4) to [inductor,l_=\SI{2}{\henry}] (7,-4);
%mosfet
\draw (3,-5.5) node[njfet] (fet) {} 
(fet.G) node[anchor=south]  {G}
(fet.D) node[anchor=north east] {D}
(fet.S) node[anchor=south east] {S};
\draw (9.5,-2.6) node[rotate=90,right]{10 $k \Omega$};
% circuit & labels
\draw (7.7,-2.4) node [rotate=90,right]{\SI{1}{\micro\farad}};
\draw (fet.D) -- (3,-4);
\draw (3,-7) -- (fet.S)
(5,-7) node[ground] {};
\draw [->,>=latex] (0,-6.8) -- (0,-0.2) node[below=0.7cm,right=0.1cm] {$V_{in}$};
\draw [->,>=latex] (10.5,-3.6) -- (10.5,-0.4) node[below=0.7cm,right=0.1cm] {$V_{out}$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had the very same error in a `beamer` presentation, thanks !